# Fill vue-multiselect with router-links

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router, vue-multiselect

I am trying to fill the vue-multiselect dropdown with `<router-link>` options. The usual way to specify router links to different components is declaratively in `<template>`, while vue-multiselect uses bind with options array. Any ideas how to go through with this?

I want to reuse vue-multiselect for navigation between components.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, after contacting Damian, developer of vue-multiselect, I've got the answer. The idea is to use the vue-multiselect as action dispatcher: https://vue-multiselect.js.org/#sub-action-dispatcher

You add

```
:reset-after="true"
@select=“navigateTo"
```

And in navigateTo you do `this.$router.push({ path: 'xyz' })`.